# Data folder not deleted when app is uninstalled

Tags: android, android-backup-service

When I uninstall my app, I want the **Android> data > (package name) folder** to also be deleted.

I added the following code to my manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:fullBackupOnly="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
```

But the folder is still left behind. I checked the device's Backup and Restore settings, but it is turned off.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can implement a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for app uninstall intents. When such a broadcast is intercepted, you can manually delete the file in the data folder.

Comment: I see. But I thought there would just be a parameter to change.

Comment: No, that's not the case.